# Cursor in the procedure doesn't loop all the rows

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

```
BEGIN

    DECLARE finished INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE v_year INT;
    DECLARE month INT DEFAULT 1;
    DECLARE year_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT Year FROM YEAR;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET finished := 1;
    OPEN year_cursor;
    YEARLOOP: LOOP
        FETCH year_cursor into v_year;
        IF finished=1 THEN      
        LEAVE YEARLOOP;     
        END IF;             

        MONTHLOOP: LOOP
            IF month > 12 THEN
            LEAVE MONTHLOOP;
            END IF;
            SELECT CONCAT(v_year,'-',month,'-%');           
            SET month = month +1;       
        END LOOP;   
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE year_cursor;                      
END
```

In the above procedure only the first row of the year table is fetched and then the outer loop exits, why is it so, Is that I didn't use the cursor properly or something else. Help needed.

Comment: What database are you using?  You've tagged this for both Oracle and MySQL.  It doesn't look like Oracle or PL/SQL so I'm guessing those two tags should be removed.

Comment: @justin 'its mysql'

Comment: what exactly are you looking for output? A ton of resultsets? How many rows do you have in the cursor table?

Comment: In the Year table, I have 10 rows so 10*12 I want 120 results but I can only get 12 results that are only the first row of the year table is fetched in the cursor and then the loop breaks, why is this happening?

Comment: I see said the blind man: `SET month = 1;` on the outside of the inner loop

Comment: I missed out setting the value everytime. Thanks a lot man.

Comment: No problem. By the way, strive to get 1 resultset coming back. 120 is a bit over the top

Comment: Thanks @Drew, I will keep this in mind.